How to Create a Case-Insensitive Search Index for Multiple Fields in MongoDB Atlas Search
I'm working with a MongoDB collection named skus and need help creating a search index and query for case-insensitive search across multiple fields with priority. Here's a sample document from the skus collection:
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "645fd8bad7318f1dad872022"
  },
  "seller_id": "133",
  "seller_sku_code": "sku-00003",
  "tenant_id": "1",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "name": "Denominations",
      "sku_attribute_variation": {
        "name": "$50"
      }
    }
  ],
  "barcodes": [
    "sku-00003",
    "sku-00004"
  ],
  "category": [],
  "created_at": {
    "$date": "2023-05-13T18:36:42.306Z"
  },
  "created_by": "3",
  "currency": "SAR",
  "description": "This is a gift card for the store",
  "dimensions": {
    "length": {},
    "breadth": {},
    "height": {}
  },
  "images": [
    {
      "default": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0756/7917/0882/products/gift_card.png?v=1682788861",
      "description": "Gift card that shows text: Generated data gift card"
    }
  ],
  "is_weighted": true,
  "name": "Gift Card - $50",
  "products": {
    "type": "simple"
  },
  "sales_channel_sku_identifier": [
    "45036825346370-134"
  ],
  "sales_channel_sku_ids": [
    "45036825346370"
  ],
  "seller_sales_channel_ids": [
    "134"
  ],
  "selling_price": 50,
  "sku_configuration": {
    "weight": {
      "min": "0.000000",
      "max": "0.000000",
      "type": "kg"
    }
  },
  "status": "live",
  "type": "simple",
  "updated_at": {
    "$date": "2023-12-07T13:08:57.339Z"
  },
  "updated_by": "441",
  "is_barcode_weighted": false,
  "uom": "ea",
  "barcode_prefixes": [
    "sk"
  ],
  "number_of_pieces": {
    "$numberLong": "1"
  },
  "tax_inclusive": {
    "selling_price": false
  },
  "weight": {
    "value": 60,
    "uom": "kg"
  },
  "package_type": "ea",
  "updated_by_user": "Shashank",
  "labels": [
    {
      "id": {
        "$oid": "668238a30aa2f2e8e7ada1ec"
      },
      "name": "Hot"
    },
    {
      "id": {
        "$oid": "668238a30aa2f2e8e7ada1ec"
      },
      "name": "Hot"
    }
  ]
}

I need to create a search index and query that will:

Search the seller_sku_code field with the highest priority. If an exact match is found, it should have a higher priority than a partial (like) search.

Search the barcodes field next in priority, with exact matches given higher priority.

Include the name field in the search.

Additionally, the search should be case-insensitive but prioritize exact case matches. For instance, if documents have name values like "Apple" and "APPLE", and the user searches for "Apple", the document with "Apple" should appear before the one with "APPLE".

The search should also support multiple languages, including Arabic.


How should I create the index and construct the search query to achieve these requirements?
